# Oracle: if exists in a Oracle Database?

Tags: php, oracle

I have a little problem.
This PHP-Script automatically creates tables in an Oracle-Database.

Now I would like to check if it can create the tables in the Oracle database
gives. If yes, then these are deleted.
In mySQL this is done via "if exists".

But like in an Oracle-Database?

```
$conn = null;

include "../conn/oci_conn.php";

function dbConstructor($conn)
{

    // IDM_CATEGORY
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE "IDM_CATEGORY"(    
    "CAT_HASH"                  VARCHAR2(10), 
    "CAT_ACTIVE"                CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "CAT_NAME_DE"               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CAT_LOCATION"              VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CAT_NAME_EN"               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
    )';

    oci_execute(oci_parse($conn, $sql)) or die(oci_error());
    echo "- Table IDM_CATEGORY created successfully<br>";


    // IDM_SUBMITTERS
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE "IDM_SUBMITTERS"(  
    "SU_PERSNUM"                NUMBER(*,0), 
    "SU_IDHASH"                 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SU_PERCENT"                FLOAT(126)
    )';

    oci_execute(oci_parse($conn, $sql)) or die(oci_error());
    echo "- Table IDM_SUBMITTERS created successfully<br>";
}

dbConstructor($conn);


$conn = null;
```

Comment: Huh do not understand the question.  You want to see if a table in oracle already exists before you try to create it?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have such a construction as `if not exists` when creating tables.

Instead you have to check does the table exist on your own.

This can be done by looking for records in table `USER_TABLES`:

`select count(*) from USER_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'`

You can perform that select beforehand:

```
<?php
    ...
    $sql = 'select count(*) from USER_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = \'IDM_CATEGORY\'';
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql) or die(oci_error());
    oci_execute($stmt) or die(oci_error());
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_NUM);
    oci_free_statement($stmt);

    if (empty($row[0])) { // got zero
       $sql = 'CREATE TABLE "IDM_CATEGORY"(   
       ...
       )';

       oci_execute(oci_parse($conn, $sql)) or die(oci_error());
       echo "- Table IDM_CATEGORY created successfully<br>"
    } else {
       echo "- Table IDM_CATEGORY already exists!<br>"
    }
```

Or, another approach: you can perform a pl/sql block at Oracle's side. You cannot perform `create table` inside a pl/sql block, but you can use `execute immediate`:

```
<?php
 ...
 $sql = '
declare
  vCnt number;
begin
  select count(*) into vCnt from USER_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = \'IDM_CATEGORY\';
  if vCnt = 0 then
    execute immediate \`
      CREATE TABLE "IDM_CATEGORY"(    
        "CAT_HASH"                  VARCHAR2(10), 
        "CAT_ACTIVE"                CHAR(1 BYTE), 
        "CAT_NAME_DE"               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
        "CAT_LOCATION"              VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "CAT_NAME_EN"               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
      )\';
  end if;
end;
';

    oci_execute(oci_parse($conn, $sql)) or die(oci_error());
    echo "- Table IDM_CATEGORY created successfully<br>";
```

**UPD**

If you want to *drop* table which does exist before recreating it (I'm not sure is it a good practice, because the table can contain some useful data), you can use the same approach, just invert the logic: perform `drop` only when the table exists.

Or you can perform a simpler pl/sql which will just mute ORA-00942 exception:

```sql
begin
  execute immediate 'drop table YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
exception
  when others then
    if SQLCODE <> -942 then -- Mute only ORA-00942: Table or view does not exists
      raise; -- reraise others
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: A PL/SQL solution is good, since it reduces 'round-trips' between PHP and Oracle DB, thus helping performance and scalability.  I read the original question as wanting to drop any existing table.